# how to create a server for large number of images and access them in android app

Tags: android, image, server, web-hosting

I'm developing an android app which involves a lot of images to be displayed. I cant store those images locally because the total size of images will be around 300 mb. So my question is, how do I store those images somewhere (like a server) and access them in the android app? I have looked through other questions but they talk about having a database and information about each user which I dont require. 
I just want to store those images which will be of fixed size (user wont upload images) and display them in android using a http request.

Can I use google drive for doing this? I also read that google drive has some limit on the usage of public folders. So I dont think I can use that.

Any other way? like some free image hosting site or free server or something similar? 
Or do I have to pay and use amazon web services or something similar?
I have zero knowledge about web services and servers.

Answer (score 0):

actually where you want to use your app means you want use as personally or in business purpose .
If you use for business purpose then you take space on any server by paying some amount or you use just testing purpose then you use your local system as server by installing wamp.

Comment: I want to publish that app. So many requests should be handled by that server. Is there any free way that I can do this? like using free storage providers like dropbox or something ?

Comment: I think any service provider not given free space to you which handle so many request